How to parse "structured" input tag data with using Jquery so I can send it via jQuery AJAX?
I need to submit unknown input data from within an element such as a div using Jquery. FYI, I can't use a form element because this data might already be inside a form.
The input names need to be, for lack of better words, "structured" in some way because they could be anything and I won't know ahead of time, similar to:
    <div id="mydata">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="custom:firstname">
        <br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="custom:lastname">
        <br>
        Favorite Ice Cream: <input type="text" name="custom:icecream">
        <br>
        <button id="submitmydata">Submit</button>
    </div>

I know how to process and send input field data if I already know all the input field names, but in this case with unknown variations of custom:something for the input field names I'm at a loss. The field names don't have to be named custom:something, I just don't know what else to name them to get this to work.
Is there a way to create and parse this kind of random data so I can send it with jquery ajax without using form tags?
Something I can do to this to send that custom style data?
    var mydata = somehow parse all "custom:whatever" here
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/myurl.html',
        data: { customdata: mydata },
        type: 'POST'
    });

I searched stackoverflow and various web tutorials but didn't find what I needed to make this happen. JS is not my primary coding language so I might be missing something simple.

You can loop over all of the <input> elements and record their names/values.  For example:


$('#submitmydata').on('click', () => {
  const myObj = {};
  $('#mydata input').each((i, el) => myObj[el.name] = el.value);
  console.log(myObj);
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydata">
  First Name: <input type="text" name="custom:firstname">
  <br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="custom:lastname">
  <br>
  Favorite Ice Cream: <input type="text" name="custom:icecream">
  <br>
  <button id="submitmydata">Submit</button>
</div>




jQuery isn't even necessary:


document.querySelector('#submitmydata').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const myObj = {};
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#mydata input');
  for (const i of inputs) {
    myObj[i.name] = i.value;
  }
  console.log(myObj);
});
<div id="mydata">
  First Name: <input type="text" name="custom:firstname">
  <br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="custom:lastname">
  <br>
  Favorite Ice Cream: <input type="text" name="custom:icecream">
  <br>
  <button id="submitmydata">Submit</button>
</div>




Why not translate jQuery .each() into vanilla .forEach()?

Your suggestion helped me solve the problem. After I added const jsonData = JSON.stringify(myObj); and then sent jsonData via ajax I was able to parse the data on the back end and do exactly what I needed to do.
